# What to do if there's not much space for improvement on a question?

Tags: discussion

I've been coming over this question

[unordered_multimap approach to adjacency list and graph search](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151126/unordered-multimap-approach-to-adjacency-list-and-graph-search)

which specifically asks about

> I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the usage of modern C++ features with this simple graph search algorithm, particularly with regard to the use of STL containers and lambda expressions.

As far as I can see that's all done fine, and I have no idea how to improve that further.

Does that deserve an answer like

*Your code is fine don't worry*

Maybe with some additional note, that it's good to use `auto` keywords and lambda expressions?

How should such question be handled?

Comment: You can very well make an answer that covers all of OP's code, while explaining *why* the code is perfect as it is. I did that once or twice, and happened to actually notice something (a comment IIRC) I would have done differently.